# React native js regex number with comma, without a point, space and a line

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, validation, numbers

I have a numeric type input field on an app on react-native.

This field must accept comma numbers only.

So I used:
`keyboardType="numeric"`

But in this case it is still possible to use characters such as point, space and line (-).
In addition to any errors in entering incorrect number data.

The correct format should be this: `nnn,ddd`

Can you give me a hand?

```js
let a = [
  "0",//0
  "0,5",//0,5
  "0,,5",//0,5
  "0.5",//0,5
  "0..5",//0,5
  ".0.5",//0,5
  ",0,5",//0,5
  "0.-5,",//0,5
  "0,-5.",//0,5
  "0,5-..",//0,5
  "0,,,- 5,,",//0,5
  "0...5-  ",//0,5,
  "0,5,"//0.5,
];

a.map(el=> {
  const e = el
  .replaceAll('.', ',')
  .replace(/[^0-9,]/g, '')
  console.log(e)
});
```

Edit:

```js
let a = [
  "0",//0
  "0,5",//0,5
  "0,,5",//0,5
  "0.5",//0,5
  "0..5",//0,5
  ".0.5",//0,5
  ",0,5",//0,5
  "0.-5,",//0,5
  "0,-5.",//0,5
  "0,5-..",//0,5
  "0,,,- 5,,",//0,5
  "0...5-  ",//0,5,
  
  "00,5",//0,5
  "00,05",//0,05
  "05,512",//5,51
  "00,5123",//0,51
  ",05",//0,05
  "00,,5",//0,5
  "21,"//21
];
```

- There cannot be two leading zeros:  "00,5",//0,5 "00,05",//0,05
- There must be no leading zero if it is then followed by a number without first having a comma: "05,512"//5,51
- After the comma there must be only two digits "00,5123"//0,51
- Last but I think you can also ignore this case, if the field is empty a comma or a point is put, at the beginning a zero is put followed by a comma: ",05",//0,05

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
let a = [
  "0",//0
  "0,5",//0,5
  "0,,5",//0,5
  "0.5",//0,5
  "0..5",//0,5
  ".0.5",//0,5
  ",0,5",//0,5
  "0.-5,",//0,5
  "0,-5.",//0,5
  "0,5-..",//0,5
  "0,,,- 5,,",//0,5
  "0...5-  ",//0,5,
  
  "00,5",//0,5
  "00,05",//0,05
  "05,512",//5,51
  "00,5123",//0,51
  ",05",//0,05
  "00,,5",//0,5
  "21,"//21
];

a.map(el=> {
  const e = el
  .replace(/^[.,]+(?=[^.,]*$)/, '0,') // Add 0 before the first . or ,  if they are single
  .replace(/^\D+|\D+$|[^0-9,.]/g, '') // remove all non-digits on both sides and non-digits except . and , in the middle
  .replace(/[,.]+/g, ',') // all commas/dots to commas
  .replace(/^0+(?=\d)|,(?=[^,]*,)|(,\d{2})\d+$/g, '$1') // remove leading zeros, all commas but last, and all fractional digits after 2nd
  console.log(el,'=>',e);
});
```

Here,

- `.replace(/^[.,]+(?=[^.,]*$)/, '0,')` - adds `0` before the first `.` or `,`  if they are the only comma/dot(s) in the string
- `.replace(/^\D+|\D+$|[^0-9,.]/g, '')` - removes all non-digits on both sides of the string and non-digits except `.` and `,` in the middle of the string
- `.replace(/[,.]+/g, ',')` - replaces all commas/dots with a comma
- `.replace(/^0+(?=\d)|,(?=[^,]*,)|(,\d{2})\d+$/g, '$1')` - removes leading zeros, all commas but last, and all fractional digits after the second fractional digit.

In your code, you should allow a comma at the end:

```js
price: price
    .replace(/(,[^,]*)[,.]$/, '$1') // remove trailing comma/dot if there is a comma already
    .replace(/^[.,]+(?=[^.,]*$)/, '0,') // Add 0 before the first . or ,  if they are single
    .replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, '') // remove all non-digits on both sides and non-digits except . and , in the middle
    .replace(/[,.]+/g, ',') // all commas/dots to commas
    .replace(/^0+(?=\d)|,(?=[^,]*,)|(,\d{2})\d+$/g, '$1') // remove leading zeros, all commas but last, and all fractional digits after 2nd
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work it would be possible to add the following restrictions:

Comment: - There cannot be two leading zeros:  "00,5",//0,5 "00,05",//0,05

Comment: - There must be no leading zero if it is then followed by a number without first having a comma: "05,512"//5,51

Comment: - After the comma there must be only two digits "00,5123"//0,51

Comment: - Last but I think you can also ignore this case, if the field is empty a comma or a point is put, at the beginning a zero is put followed by a comma: ",05",//0,05

Comment: Logically it seems to work but when I try it realistically it doesn't work, as soon as I try to put the comma or the dot doesn't make them insert I'm trying it on react native.
If you want to see here is the online example on snacks, then see the web version, if not then try it on the emulator.

Line 151: https://snack.expo.io/1YXNA_Xiu

Comment: @Paul That means you must allow a `,` at the end of string. `21,` case is invalid.

Comment: @Paul Did you try my updated code in your fiddle? I think it works as expected, and the comma at the end is necessary, or there will be no way to type it in. You may combine the live input sanitization with final input validation, using `pattern="\d+(?:,\d+)?"`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of a hybrid string manipulation mixed with regex. Turned into a bit of a monster with the edited conditions, but here goes:

```
a.map(el => {
  const e = el
  /* normalize decimals */
    .replaceAll('.', ',')       
  /* break into array */
    .split(",")
  /* add a starting zero  */     
    .map((e,i) => i === 0 ? "0"+e : e)       
  /* get rid of empties (extra commas) */
    .filter(e => e)       
  /* only work with the last 2 */
    .splice(-2)  
  /* remove non-numbers */                                           
    .map(e => e.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))                    
  /* trim index 0 & 1 */
    .map((e, i) => i === 0 ? (+e || "0") : e.substr(0, 2)) 
  /* reassemble */ 
    .join(",");                                             
  console.log(el, '=>', e)
});
```

```js
let a = [
  "0", //0
  "0,5", //0,5
  "0,,5", //0,5
  "0.5", //0,5
  "0..5", //0,5
  ".0.5", //0,5
  ",0,5", //0,5
  "0.-5,", //0,5
  "0,-5.", //0,5
  "0,5-..", //0,5
  "0,,,- 5,,", //0,5
  "0...5-  ", //0,5,

  "00,5", //0,5
  "00,05", //0,05
  "05,512", //5,51
  "00,5123", //0,51
  ",05", //0,05
  "00,,5", //0,5
  "21," //21
];


a.map(el => {
  const e = el.replaceAll('.', ',').split(",").map((e,i) => i === 0 ? "0"+e : e).filter(e => e).splice(-2).map(e => e.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')).map((e, i) => i === 0 ? (+e || "0") : e.substr(0, 2)).join(","); 
  console.log(el, '=>', e)
});
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work it would be possible to add the following restrictions:

Comment: - There cannot be two leading zeros:  "00,5",//0,5 "00,05",//0,05

Comment: - There must be no leading zero if it is then followed by a number without first having a comma: "05,512"//5,51

Comment: - After the comma there must be only two digits "00,5123"//0,51

Comment: - Last but I think you can also ignore this case, if the field is empty a comma or a point is put, at the beginning a zero is put followed by a comma: ",05",//0,05

Comment: It appears that the case ",05" returns 5 should return // 0,05
",05" => "0,05"
".05" => "0,05"

Comment: Updated. Probably not nearly as brief and elegant as regex, but there it is

Comment: Logically it seems to work but when I try it realistically it doesn't work, as soon as I try to put the comma or the point it doesn't make them insert, as soon as I delete the number it puts the zero and it doesn't allow me to insert other numbers I'm trying it on react native.

If you want to see here is the online example on snacks, then see the web version, if not then try it on the emulator.

Line 149: https://snack.expo.io/y2ipYgiSq

Answer (score 1):

self explained

```js
let a = [
  "0",//0
  "0,5",//0,5
  "0,,5",//0,5
  "0.5",//0,5
  "0..5",//0,5
  ".0.5",//0,5
  ",0,5",//0,5
  "0.-5,",//0,5
  "0,-5.",//0,5
  "0,5-..",//0,5
  "0,,,- 5,,",//0,5
  "0...5-  ",//0,5,
  "0,5,"//0.5
];

a.map(el=> {
  const e = el
  .replace(/\D+/g, ',') // replace non digit with comma
  .replace(/^,|,$/g, '') // trim the comma
  console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: Thank you seems to work it would be possible to add the following restrictions:

Comment: - There cannot be two leading zeros:  "00,5",//0,5 "00,05",//0,05

Comment: - There must be no leading zero if it is then followed by a number without first having a comma: "05,512"//5,51

Comment: - After the comma there must be only two digits "00,5123"//0,51

Comment: - Last but I think you can also ignore this case, if the field is empty a comma or a point is put, at the beginning a zero is put followed by a comma: ",05",//0,05